# Set print orientation to landscape

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

i already can create a print to print a file in my windows forms. However, whenever i add this code:

```
printDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

I can't see the Orientation of the page become LandScape, it is still Portrait.

How do I make it LandScape as default? So, whenever i click PrintPreview or PrintFile, the Orientation of the page will become LandScape, not Portrait.

Here is the code:

```
private void PrintPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintPreviewDialog _PrintPreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    _PrintPreview.Document = printDocument1;
    ((Form)_PrintPreview).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    _PrintPreview.ShowDialog();
}

private void PrintFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
    printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

    if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you adding that line before calling ShowDialog()?

Comment: yes, i added that line right before call the ShowDialog();, though i called it in PrintFile function

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try setting the `Landscape` of PrintDocument as follows,

```
printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

Comment: and, what is the `page` sir?

Comment: This is good. Be advised that `printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;` did not work. Make sure you have just like the answer and not with `PrinterSettings`.

Answer (score 0):

The pdfprinting.net library is excellent for implementing the print functionality and be productive. Here is the simple code snippet to set print orientation to landscape(pdfPrint.IsLandscape = true;)

```
var pdfPrint = new PdfPrint("demoCompany", "demoKey");
string pdfFile = @"c:\test\test.pdf";
pdfPrint.IsLandscape = true;

int numberOfPages = pdfPrint.GetNumberOfPages(pdfFile);
var status = pdfPrint.Print(pdfFile);
if (status == PdfPrint.Status.OK) { 
     // check the result status of the Print method
     // your code here
}
// if you have pdf document in byte array that is also supported
byte[] pdfContent = YourCustomMethodWhichReturnsPdfDocumentAsByteArray();
status = pdfPrint.Print(pdfFile);
```