Get printer's default page orientation
I have a C# .NET 8.0 console application, intended to run on Windows 10. How can I get installed printer's (let's say "Microsoft Print to PDF") default page orientation?^

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136763/set-print-orientation-to-landscape

@DmitryBychenko thanks, but that is about setting :( Can't get the orientation with PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings. I believe I need WMI for that. This post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296182/how-to-get-printer-info-in-net allows to get lots of info about printer, but no page orientation there

(source: https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_printerconfiguration#orientation )
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PrinterConfiguration | Select-Object -Property Name, Orientation

Values for orientation (found after a short test):

1 = Portrait
2 = Landscape

